# SSL vs IPsec what's the difference

Tags: tls, ipsec, vpn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference in security between a VPN- and a SSL-connection?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1476/what-is-the-difference-in-security-between-a-vpn-and-a-ssl-connection)

Which is more secure? And offer better access control?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1476/what-is-the-difference-in-security-between-a-vpn-and-a-ssl-connection