# What is important when selecting a VPN provider?

Tags: vpn

I am new to using a VPN service and came across the past at [How do I pick a VPN provider?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3973/how-do-i-pick-a-vpn-provider) however am unsure if I need to use a personal VPN service or if OpenVPN fits my needs which are as follows;

- No logging whatever so e.g. encrypted servers, no tracking of originating IP address, etc
- Minimal or next to no impact on speed
- The ability to use the service on multiple computers without having to purchase a new router
- Unlimited downloads and uploads
- Works with all web related applications e.g. web browsing, video streaming, chatting, audio streaming, etc
- Reliable support and service

Comment: Everything that you listed, can be acomplished with OpenVPN. I think the questions that really matter are: * Which SLA you need? Can you survive if, saturday night your VPN doesn't work? * if not, can you afford 24 x 7 support?

Comment: Your question would do better as an answer to the one you cite, and is otherwise a duplicate of it, unless the focus is changed to be about OpenVPN (which would make the comment yet more appropriate as an answer).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I pick a VPN provider?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3973/how-do-i-pick-a-vpn-provider)

Comment: @VP01 - Thanks. When you say which SLA what are you referring to exactly? How expensive is it to have 24 x 7 support?

Comment: @nealmcb - I disagree that the question is a duplicate as I am asking specific questions as to what is important to know when selecting a provider as opposed to how do I pick a VPN provider which is vague.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey well SLA - service level agreement or how much availability do you want. for example 99%, 99.9%, doesn´t matter etc.
to calculate the 24 x 7 support you must add 2 or 3 network admins workin in turns and so on

Comment: @VP01 - I would prefer a service that that 99.9 uptime. Althought important I would be keen to know what else I need to be aware of e.g. type of security, etc

Answer (score 2):

> No logging whatever so e.g. encrypted servers, no tracking of originating IP address, etc

Most VPN providers will do only the minimal logging. Ask the support staff for exact details before signing up

> Minimal or next to no impact on speed

The closer the server is to your location, the faster the speed will be. VPN's have a speed impact due to no cache on encryted data. Some VPN services, such as Astrill.com include a system in their software that recreates the cache localy (if turned on) speeding up the system slightly.

> The ability to use the service on multiple computers without having to purchase a new router

Most VPNs are simple software installs on your PC. Usually the end user agreement allows you to install on multiple computers as long as only one is used at a time. If you want to use multiple computers on the VPN at the same time, you may need to buy additional keys to access the network. Again ask the support staff as this may vary.

> Unlimited downloads and uploads

There are many VPNs who offer unlimited traffic. Look on their websites or ask the support for details.

> Works with all web related applications e.g. web browsing, video streaming, chatting, audio streaming, etc

All VPNs I've tried work with the services you listed.

Comment: Thanks. Which service would you recommend and why?

Comment: I can recommend Astrill because that is who I use myself. Whither they suit your needs, I don't know. In the past I tried Witopia - not the best designed system. I also use VPNUK though they only have a small choice of server locations.