# Do we need vpn now that we have browser with https enabled?

Tags: http, vpn, openvpn, sslstrip, tls-intercept

I understand that vpn is used to encrypt our data before sending it to a server on the internet so that no one can read our data (for eg in man in the middle attack).

Now that we have browser with https enabled by default and encrypt the data by default with no intervention of user (and also gives warning of we are visiting a site which doesn't support https), do we still need vpn for security?

Comment: This question might be helpful. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1476/what-is-the-difference-in-security-between-a-vpn-and-a-ssl-connection

Comment: https doesn't keep your isp from tracking each site you visit, VPNs do.